# Place files at root of JAR

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am coding a minecraft mod and I want to set a icon.
I need to place the image file at the root of JAR file (it is what the example code says):

```
# A file name (in the root of the mod JAR) containing a logo for display
logoFile="examplemod.png" #optional
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcnuc.png

Where in my project do I place the image file?
Remember, I need the image file to keep at root of JAR file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `maven` it will be `resources`.

Answer (score 0):

The logo must be in the root of the JAR or directly in the root of the source set (e.g., src/main/resources for the main source set). so put the image folder in the resources folder not in the META-INF folder just in the resource folder together with the pack.mcmeta file